No holomorphic functions on $T\mathbb{P}^1$
Is it true that $H^0(T\mathbb{P}^1,\mathcal{O}_{T\mathbb{P^1}})=\mathbb{C}$? I think it should be, any function $f$ has to be constant on the zero section and also on the projective curves gotten by deforming the zero section along the normal bundle to it, we can do that because there is a non zero global holomorphic vector field on $\mathbb{P}^1$, and these cover all of $T\mathbb{P}^1$, and have non empty intersections with one another because of the hairy ball theorem, so $f$ is a constant. The same argument should work if we replace $T\mathbb{P}^1$ with $T^\vee\Sigma$ with $g_\Sigma \geq 2$. Is there a cleaner argument? This one sounds shady. I tried to make it say something absurd for $\mathbb{P}^1\times \mathbb{A}^1$ but it doesn't, because the only projective curves on that surface are the translates $\mathbb{P}^1\times\{\lambda\}$ I think.
By contrast if we replace tangent bundle by cotangent bundle, then we have a lot of functions, because the cotangent bundle to $\mathbb{P}^1$ has a birational morphism to an affine quadric surface. But in this case the zero section is rigid so there is no contradiction.

Do you know about degrees of line bundles?

Yes I know about them

It is ok, but you do not need to invoke the "hairy ball" theorem, it is more elementary than that, as you can explicitly define a vector field on $P^1$ which has prescribed value at any given point or just use automorphisms of $P^1$ to achieve the same result.
